# Bind multiple keys to a command using `global-set-key` interactively

Tags: key-bindings

I want to bind multiple keys interactively to a single function using `global-set-key`.

For example, let `M-. g` bind to `project-find-file` function.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`M-x global-set-key`, followed by hitting the key and entering the command to bind to it.

Do that twice, once for each key.

You ask how to *interactively* bind multiple keys. That's the way. There's no special provision for binding multiple keys to the same command using a single command invocation.

But you can use `M-p` to retrieve your command-name input, `project-find-file` for the second binding, so you don't have to type/complete it again.